# Swipe Refresh freezes when executing async task

Tags: java, android

I'm encountering a problem, when I try running an asynchronous task on refresh using a swipe refresh layout it "freezes" and doesn't rotate. When the task is done it just disappears.

Here is my code:

HotActivityFragment.java:

```
public class HotActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    ListView hotList;
    SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
    Context context;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    HotListAdapter hotListAdapter;
    public HotActivityFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hot, container, false);
        context = getContext();
        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout);
        hotList = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.hotListView);
        hotList.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener(getActivity()));
        sharedPreferences = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        try {
            ArrayList<ListTypeItem> initial_list = new DownloadPosts(getActivity()).execute().get();
            this.hotListAdapter = new HotListAdapter(getContext(), initial_list);
            hotList.setAdapter(hotListAdapter);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("Download Error", e.toString());
        }
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                retrievePosts();
            }

        });
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.accentColor, R.color.backgroundColor);



        return view;
    }
    public void retrievePosts()
    {
        // showing refresh animation before making http call
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

        //shared preferences = empty
        sharedPreferences.edit().putString("last_time_downloaded", "empty").commit();
        try {
            ArrayList<ListTypeItem> listItems = new DownloadPosts(getActivity(), mSwipeRefreshLayout).execute().get();
            hotListAdapter.updateList(listItems);
            hotListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Download Error", e.toString());
        }

        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

        //for testing purposes
//        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
//            @Override public void run() {
//                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
//            }
//        }, 5000);
    }
    }
```

DownloadPosts.java:

```
public class DownloadPosts  extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<ListTypeItem>> {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

    public DownloadPosts(Activity activity)
    {
        this.sharedPreferences = activity.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
    public DownloadPosts(Activity activity, SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout)
    {
        this.sharedPreferences = activity.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        this.swipeRefreshLayout = swipeRefreshLayout;
    }
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<ListTypeItem> doInBackground(Void... args)
    {
        StringBuilder parsedString = new StringBuilder();

        ArrayList<ListTypeItem> downloadList = new ArrayList<>();
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

        if(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("Thomas More",false))
        {
            str.append("190155257998823,");
        }

        String school_url = str.toString();
        if(school_url.length() > 0)
        {
            school_url = school_url.substring(0, str.length()-1);
        }
        try{
            String date = "";
            //checken of opnieuw moet bepaald worden
            // + in de adapter moet als gereload wordt last_time_downloaded == empty
            if(!sharedPreferences.getString("last_time_downloaded","empty").equals("empty"))
            {
                String last_date = sharedPreferences.getString("last_time_downloaded","nothing");
                last_date = last_date.replace(" ","T");
                date= "&datum_last_posted=" + last_date;
            }
            URL url = new URL("http://localhost/getpostlist.php?school_post=" + school_url + date);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String json;
            while((json = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null)
            {
                parsedString.append(json + "/n");
            }
            String s = parsedString.toString().trim();
            //converten van string opgehaald via http naar jsonobject
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(s);
            for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject tempObj = array.getJSONObject(i);
                School_WithoutImage tempSchool = new School_WithoutImage(tempObj.getString("school_id"),
                        tempObj.getString("post_message"),tempObj.getInt("views"),tempObj.getInt("likes")
                        ,tempObj.getInt("post_id"),tempObj.getString("datum_posted"));
                downloadList.add(tempSchool);
                if(i == array.length()-1) {
                    sharedPreferences.edit().putString("last_time_downloaded",tempObj.getString("datum_posted")).commit();
                }
            }
            JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(0);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
        }

        return downloadList;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ListTypeItem> result)
    {
        if(this.swipeRefreshLayout != null)
        {
//            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    }

}
```

I have no idea why the swiperefreshview doesn't spin. Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the call to `get()`:

```
.execute().get()
```

Forces the UI thread to wait for the `AsyncTask` to finish.

Instead you should look at doing this in the `onPostExecute` method:

```
 protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ListTypeItem> listItems) {
      hotListAdapter.updateList(listItems);
      hotListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 }
```

Comment: I tried to put it in the onPostExecute before but totally forgot about removing .get() , thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Because you are waiting for the result from asynctask by calling get just after execute. And further passing it to list.

You can use Local Broadcast Listener or can create an interface and can us that as callback, without freezing UI